# Remove columns based on specific criteria from multiple data frames with same column structures

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have 4 data frames for 4 different data groups (total 16 data frames) with the same column structure each having column a, b, c, d etc. (over hundreds of columns), but the values are different for each data frame. The only thing that are the same are the number of variables and column names (to some degree, but there is no pattern. The column names are names for items, not a, b, c etc.) for each "data group".

For example:

```
dat1 = data.frame(x = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5),
                  y = c(0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.10), 
                  z = c(0.12,0.13,0.14,0.15,0.16))
```

which produces

```
   x   y    z
1 0.1 0.6 0.12
2 0.2 0.7 0.13
3 0.3 0.8 0.14
4 0.4 0.9 0.15
5 0.5 0.1 0.16
```

and second data frame

```
dat2 = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5), y = c(6,7,8,9,10), z = c(12,13,14,15,16))

  x  y  z
1 1  6 12
2 2  7 13
3 3  8 14
4 4  9 15
5 5 10 16
```

I want to do my data cleaning in `dat1` based on certain criteria, such that if I remove column `x` in `dat1` then column `x` will also be removed in `dat2`. These specific criteria could be

```
dat1[,tail(dat1, n = 1) < 0.2] 

   y    z
1 0.6 0.12
2 0.7 0.13
3 0.8 0.14
4 0.9 0.15
5 0.1 0.16
```

such that `dat2` also automatically deletes colunm `x`.

```
   y  z
1  6 12
2  7 13
3  8 14
4  9 15
5 10 16
```

Is there a way to do this? I have been trying to search for it on StackOverflow, but I couldn't find anything useful. Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming you want it "automatically" deleted? Otherwise you can simply do something along the lines of: `dat2[, names(dat1)]`

Comment: @MikeH. Yes. I would want it automatically deleted. I want columns in each data frame automatically deleted when it is deleted in `dat1`.

Comment: May I ask why you need behaviour like that? What is wrong with subseting to the same columns in `dat2`?

Comment: @MikeH I guess it works. Does your method assume that I would do all of the cleaning and manipulating in `dat1`, and then use `dat2[, names(dat1)]`, `dat3[, names(dat1)]`, `dat4[, names(dat1)]`  etc.?

Comment: @MikeH. Hi again. your suggestion `dat2[, names(dat1)]` worked perfectly. However, is there something similar for rows in the sense that I want the rows to be similar to `dat1` after omitting rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?
With the data you posted, it works as expected.

```
cols.to.remove <- function(DF1, DF2) {
    d <- setdiff(names(DF1), names(DF2))
    -which(d %in% names(DF1))
}


dat2 <- dat2[cols.to.remove(dat2, dat1)]
dat2
#   y  z
#1  6 12
#2  7 13
#3  8 14
#4  9 15
#5 10 16
```